# Should I declare a multiplier number as a constant or use it directly as written without declaring?

Tags: c++, variables, constants, declaration

When it comes to multiplying a constant number, in terms of performance / code optimization, is it more efficient to declare it as a constant ? (see pi in first code example below) :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double const pi = 3.14;
    int nb;
    cin >> nb;
    double mul_pi = pi * nb;
    return 0;
}
```

Or should I rather put it directly in the code without declaring it ? (see second code example below) :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nb;
    cin >> nb;
    double mul_pi = 3.14 * nb;
    return 0;
}
```

Many Thanks in advance !

Comment: It should not make any difference at all in terms of performance. But using constants is faaaaar better in terms of readability and maintainability. 
I am always using [constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) for compile time constant expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Since pi is a number which will never change, yes you should store it as a constant.

Another option is to include the math.h library and access M_PI:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nb;
    cin >> nb;
    double mul_pi = M_PI * nb;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To add to this, it's always beneficial to store unchanging parameters in constants - by doing so, you're making it easier to make small changes down the line (and preventing small differences in the inline-written value from affecting code output).